# Update root crontab remotely for many systems by script

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to update the crontab file of 1000+ systems using a for loop from jump host.

The below doesn't work.

```
echo -e 'pass365\!\n' | sudo -S echo 'hello' >> /var/spool/cron/root
-bash: /var/spool/cron/root: Permission denied
```

I do have (ALL) ALL in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another solution;

```
echo 'pass365\!' | sudo -S bash -c 'echo "hello">> /var/spool/cron/root'
```

Comment: I have another problem. ssh -t $i "echo 'pass365\!' | sudo -S bash -c 'echo "hello">> /var/spool/cron/root'"
have 2 more double quotes to add.

Comment: @KevinM : post a new question or update your existing. Asking for help in a comment is "not the done thing, old man" ;-) Good luck.

Comment: This may help http://backreference.org/2011/08/10/running-local-script-remotely-with-arguments/

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for me.

```
echo 'pass365\!' | sudo -S echo 'hello' | sudo -S tee -a /var/spool/cron/root > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: You are trying to send the password via echo to sudo.
Problem 2: You can't use shell redirection in a sudo command like that.

Between the two of these, consider setting up ssh public key authorization and doing

```
ssh root@host "echo 'hello' \>\> /var/spool/cron/root"
```

You may eventually get sudo working but it will be so much more pain than this.